# Why is the word weirdo synonymous with pervert?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

On the website Oxford Dictionary, pervert is a synonym for weirdo. Weirdo - a person who is eccentric, while pervert means - abnormal sexual behavior. What makes these words synonyms? Because to me I think weirdo just means someone who likes things most people don't. Please help!

Comment: Why do you think they are synonyms? I don't think most people would consider them synonyms.

Comment: Related: [Why is 'weird' given a sexual connotation nowadays?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214594/why-is-weird-given-a-sexual-connotation-nowadays)

Comment: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/weirdo) gives two senses:  << **weirdo** noun, plural weirdos. Informal. $1. an odd, eccentric, or unconventional person. // $2. a psychopath, especially a dangerous or vicious one; psycho:
_They caught the weirdo who attacked the children_.>> Synonyms share senses (not necessarily all senses).

Comment: Basically, "weirdo" got hit by a double whammy:  It came to be used as a euphemism for "pervert", and it came to be used to describe people about whom one is "not quite sure".  But this does not mean you can't, eg, say "Frank is a bit of a weirdo" without implying that Frank is a pedophile or something of that nature.

Comment: In a living language, words shift in meaning. *Gay* meant happy, enjoying oneself, being outgoing, perhaps a little inebriated.  It still does, but most people will interpret it as *homosexual*. Maybe *gay* can shift again, with the PC army pushing for *LGBTQ*. (Yes, I know "gay" is buried in there. Let it stay buried. I want my gay back!  )

Answer (score 2):

Maintaining your definitions...

" Weirdo - a person who is eccentric, while pervert means - abnormal sexual behavior."

...if a pervert [engages in?] abnormal sexual behavior, and to be eccentric means to behave in strange, abnormal, unexpected (etc) ways...then a pervert could be seen as a particular variety of eccentric.  I think there are probably many usage guides that would have definitions for "weirdo" that more closely approach "pervert".

There is probably a closer connection than one would imagine if we look REAL far back...

Eccentric's Greek roots carry a meaning of being out of sync or alignment with the world.  Weird was an old English/Germanic word describing fate, doom, etc. that was "relaunched" in MACBETH after having more or less faded from use (except in the Scottish it would seem).  The word undoubtedly became branded with connotative reactions to the characters.  Pervert derives from a Latin verb meaning to corrupt, subvert, etc.  To pervert someone was to steer him off course, corrupt his thinking, overthrow his mind.  One could argue that by heeding the Weird[o]s (so to speak), Macbeth perverted himself.  He certainly was eccentric.